# Pytorch model accuracy stuck at 10%

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I was trying to train a CNN model with CIFAR-10 dataset and while the training I noticed
the accuracy is stuck at 10% from the start. My best guess is that the accuracy is not properly updating, but I still can't figure out why this is happening.
Below is the part of my code where I defined,trained and found accuracy of my CNN model.

```
# Define CNN
class CNNModel_b1(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CNNModel_b1, self).__init__()
        
        # Layer 1: Conv2d
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3,6,5)
        # Layer 2: ReLU
        self.relu2 = nn.ReLU()
        # Layer 3: Conv2d
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(6,16,3)
        # Layer 4: ReLU
        self.relu4 = nn.ReLU()
        # Layer 4b: Maxpooling
        self.maxpool4b = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2)
        # Layer 5: Conv2d
        self.conv5 = nn.Conv2d(16,24,3)
        # Layer 6: ReLU
        self.relu6 = nn.ReLU()        
        # Layer 7: Linear (fully connected) 
        self.fc7 = nn.Linear(2904,120)
        # Layer 8: ReLU
        self.relu8 = nn.ReLU()
        # Layer 9: Linear (fully connected)
        self.fc9 = nn.Linear(120,84)
        # Layer 10: ReLU
        self.relu10 = nn.ReLU()
        # Layer 11: Linear (fully connected)
        self.fc11 = nn.Linear(84,10)

    def forward(self,x): # Giving an argument that decides whether to plot feature map. 

        global out

        # Layer 1: Conv2d
        out = self.conv1(x)
        # Layer 2: ReLU
        out = self.relu2(out)
        # Layer 3: Conv2d
        out = self.conv3(out)
        # Layer 4: ReLU
        out = self.relu4(out)
        # Layer 4b: Maxpooling
        out = self.maxpool4b(out)
        
        # Visualize the first channel of the feature map 
        # Uncomment below 3 lines to answer Part b - 1, comment for training
        # plt.imshow(out[0][0].cpu().detach().numpy())
        # plt.show()
        # plt.close('all')  
        
        # Layer 5: Conv2d
        out = self.conv5(out)
        # Layer 6: ReLU
        out = self.relu6(out)
        
        # Convert the output tensor into a 1D vector
        out = out.view(out.size(0), -1)
        
        # Layer 7: Linear (fully connected) 
        out = self.fc7(out)
        # Layer 8: ReLU
        out = self.relu8(out)
        # Layer 9: Linear (fully connected)
        out = self.fc9(out)
        # Layer 10: ReLU
        out = self.relu10(out)
        # Layer 11: Linear (fully connected)
        out = self.fc11(out)  
    
        return out
```

```
# Create CNN
device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
model_b1 = CNNModel_b1()
model_b1.to(device)

# TODO: define Cross Entropy Loss 
cross_ent = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

# TODO: create Adam Optimizer and define your hyperparameters 
# Use L2 penalty of 1e-8
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr = 1e-3, weight_decay = 1e-8)
```

```
# Train CNN
count = 0
loss_list_b1 = []
iteration_list = []
accuracy_list_b1 = []
num_epochs = 20

for epoch in tqdm(range(num_epochs)):
    model_b1.train()
    for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
        images, labels = images.to(device), labels.to(device)
        
        # Clear gradients
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        
        # TODO: Forward propagation
        out = model_b1(images)      
        
        # TODO: Calculate softmax and cross entropy loss
        loss = cross_ent(out,labels)     
        
        # Backpropagate your Loss 
        loss.backward()
        
        # Update CNN model_b1  
        optimizer.step()
        
        count += 1
        
        if count % 50 == 0:
            model_b1.eval()
            # Calculate Accuracy         
            correct = 0
            total = 0
            # Iterate through test dataset
            for images, labels in test_loader:
                images, labels = images.to(device), labels.to(device)
                
                # Forward propagation
                outputs = model_b1(images)
                
                # Get predictions from the maximum value
                predicted = torch.argmax(outputs,1)
                
                # Total number of labels
                total += len(labels)
                
                correct += (predicted == labels).sum()
            
            accuracy = 100 * correct / float(total)
            
            # store loss and iteration
            loss_list_b1.append(loss.item())
            iteration_list.append(count)
            accuracy_list_b1.append(accuracy.item())
        if count % 500 == 0:
            # Print Loss
            print('Iteration: {}  Loss: {}  Accuracy: {} %'.format(count, loss.data, accuracy))
```

Comment: why `global out` in your `forward` method?

Comment: do you shuffle the training samples? What augmentations are you using? How do you normalize the input images?

Comment: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/cifar10_tutorial.html 
I referenced this link for unnormalizing the input, also I didn't shuffle the samples.

Comment: Also I don't understand what you mean by augmentation, I'm new to Pytorch :( sorry

Comment: Shuffle your training samples.